# Replace sound in another YouTube video

Tags: video, audio, editing, youtube

I have received permission from someone to translate the audio in their movies. The problem I am facing is that the video quality is quite poor and the author does not have the original videos any more.

How can I replace the audio in the YouTube videos without further degrading the quality of the videos?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, sadly.

YouTube allows you to swap audio with their list of provided songs, but other than that you are stuck with it.

Only option is to re-upload the same video with the sound you desire.

Comment: I guess I don't have any other choice.